# postgresql write a materialized view query to include base record and no of records matching

Tags: postgresql, rdbms

I have two tables one is users and another is orders in postgresql.

## users table

```
userid  | username  | usertype
1       |   John    |  F
2       |   Bob     |  P
```

## orders table

```
userid  |   orderid | ordername
1       |   001     |   Mobile
1       |   002     |   TV
1       |   003     |   Laptop
2       |   001     |   Book
2       |   002     |   Kindle
```

Now I want to write a query for postgresql materialized view it will give me output like below

```
userid  | username | Base Order Name |No of Orders | User Type
1       | John     | Mobile          |  3          |  F - Free
2       | Bob      | Book            |  2          |  P- Premium
```

I have tried below query but it's giving five records as output instead of two records and didn't figure out how to show usertype F - Free / P - Premium

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW userorders
TABLESPACE pg_default
AS
SELECT
u.userid,
username,
(select count(orderid)  from orders where userid = u.userid)
as no_of_orders,
(select ordername  from orders where orderid=1 and userid = u.userid)
as baseorder
FROM users u
INNER JOIN orders o ON u.userid = o.userid
WITH DATA;
```

It's giving result like below

```
userid | username | no_of_orders | baseorder
1      | John     | 3            | Mobile
1      | John     | 3            | Mobile
1      | John     | 3            | Mobile
2      | Bob      | 2            | Book
2      | Bob      | 2            | Book
```

Assume base order id is always 001. In the final materialized view user type will return F - Free/ P - Premium by some mapping in query.

Comment: Did you consider aggregating data through a GROUP BY, rather than using nested queries in the SELECT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a group by and this becomes pretty trivial.  The only slightly complex part is getting the base order name, but this can be accomplished using FILTER:

```
select users.userid,
       username,
       max(ordername) FILTER (WHERE orderid='001') as "Base Order Name",
       count(orderid) as "No of Orders",
       CASE WHEN usertype = 'F' THEN 'F - Free'
            WHEN usertype = 'P' THEN 'P- Premium'
       END as "User Type"
FROM users
JOIN orders on users.userid = orders.userid
GROUP BY users.userid, users.username, users.usertype;
```

Comment: Really cool solution and it shows your expertise level. Thanks! , one more thing can you please explain why we are using max(ordername) basically we use max for numeric column type

Comment: The max is a bit distracting, but the important thing to note is that with the filter, we'll only get one possible value per group.  min(ordername) should always return exactly the same value.  We just need some sort of aggregate function there to make the SQL valid.

Comment: An alternative to max(...) would be the Windowed function "First_value (ordername) over (partition by userid 
 order by userid ) "   but it is a bit wordier